# Fabric/Fluent UI Datepicker days of week are misaligned with calendar numerical date

Tags: fluent-ui, fluentui-react

Fabric/Fluent UI Datepicker calendar numerical dates are misaligned with the actual days of the week. Screenshot to demonstrate:

[image: img_datePicker]

^ as can be seen, the highlighted today date is marked September 17th, 2020, under the calendar's Friday column, but this is clearly wrong because September 17th, 2020 is a *Thursday*.

I have considered this might be due to an error in the actual `Date()` object, but that doesn't make sense because that should only cause the date to be wrong, the alignment of calendar numerical date to day of the week should *never* be misaligned like this, as that is simply wrong no matter what. September 17th, 2020 will always be a Thursday, and not a Friday, no matter what `Date()` object you input into the Datepicker.

Is this a bug with the Fabric/Fluent UI Datepicker? Is anyone else getting this behavior, or is there something I might have overlooked?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED

The problem was that Fluent UI accepts the shortDay strings in a certain order:

`shortDays: ['S', 'M', 'T', 'W', 'T', 'F', 'S']`

(see docs: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/controls/web/datepicker)

But because in my app I need to localize for different locales, I'm using Luxon to generate the day strings like so:

`import { Info } from 'luxon';`

`shortDays: Info.weekdays('narrow', {locale: i18n.locale})`

..and that outputs as

`shortDays: ['M', 'T', 'W', 'T', 'F', 'S', 'S']`

...which causes the strings to shift X_X (Fluent UI Datepicker reads 'M' as Sunday, 'T' as Monday, etc...)

Therefore, to solve it, I dropped this one line into my render method just before I return the HTML:

`this.DayPickerStrings.shortDays.unshift(this.DayPickerStrings.shortDays.pop());`

(yeah yeah I know, class components in React are outdated, but I didn't write this code originally, I'm just inheriting it)